# Analizador léxico en C

Tags: c

Estoy haciendo una cosa deforme que parece un analizador léxico.

No quiero que me digan que vea códigos de otros compiladores o que así no se hace un tolkenizer, ya que estoy poniendo en forma mi cerebro haciendo todo lo posible por hacer el programa yo mismo.

El analizador léxico lee el código fuente hasta el fin de archivo y todo el código lo almacena en una variable para luego ser analizado.

La cosa es que estaba probando el programa antes de programar como se analiza el código, y puse una línea de prueba porque la salida tenía un caracter extraño al final (yo sabía que era por no poner un cero al final de la variable) y quería saber porqué, si sólo tenía que leer hasta el EOF, y salió esto...

Este es mi código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#if !defined(COMMENT)
#undef COMMENT
#define COMMENT "//"
#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc == 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Expected 1 argument but 0 were given\n"); // Salida si no se especifica el archivo
    }else if(argc == 2)
    {
        FILE *source = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if(source != NULL){
            printf("Compilando...\n"); // Salida si se especifica el argumento correctamente
        }else
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: Especified file does not exist\n");
            return 1;
        }
        fclose(source);
    }else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Expected 1 argument but %d were given\n", argc - 1); // Salida si se especifican argumentos de más
    }

    if(argc == 2)
    {
        char Caracter_Actual; // Variable para almacenar caracteres que se vallan leyendo
        char Entrada[999]; // Variable para almacenar el código fuente procesado
        int Contador; // Variable iteradora
        int str_state = 0; // Variable para saber si se está leyendo un string

        FILE *source = fopen(argv[1], "r"); // Apertura de el archivo en modo lectura
        rewind(source);

        for(Contador = 0; !(feof(source)); Contador++) // Lectura de el código fuente
        {
            Caracter_Actual = fgetc(source); // Obtener un caracter
            printf("\nÍndice: %d\nElemento: %d\nCaracter: %c\n", Contador, Contador + 1, Caracter_Actual);
            Entrada[Contador] = Caracter_Actual;
        }

        Entrada[Contador - 1] = 0;

        FILE *out = fopen("out.txt", "w+");
        printf("%s", Entrada);

        for(Contador = 0; Entrada[Contador] != 0; Contador++) // Escritura de el código bruto
        {
            fputc(Entrada[Contador], out);
        }

        fclose(source);
        fclose(out);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Y esta es la salida:

```
├ìndice: 0
Elemento: 1
Caracter: #

├ìndice: 1
Elemento: 2
Caracter: d

├ìndice: 2
Elemento: 3
Caracter: e

├ìndice: 3
Elemento: 4
Caracter: f

├ìndice: 4
Elemento: 5
Caracter: i

├ìndice: 5
Elemento: 6
Caracter: n

├ìndice: 6
Elemento: 7
Caracter: e

├ìndice: 7
Elemento: 8
Caracter:

├ìndice: 8
Elemento: 9
Caracter: x

├ìndice: 9
Elemento: 1
Caracter:

├ìndice: 10
Elemento: 1
Caracter: 4

├ìndice: 11
Elemento: 1
Caracter:  
#define x 4
```

La cosa está en que el contador llega a 11, pero sólo debería llegar a 10, ya que en el momento en que lee el caracter 4, el contador es igual a 10, y en la siguiente vuelta de bucle se encuentra el fin de archivo, por lo que en esa vuelta no se debería incrementar el contador ni ejecutarse el bloque de código, ya que la condición ya no se cumple...

No se si me entendieron, por lo que cualquier duda escriban un comentario...

La pregunta la hice porque me dio curiosidad el hecho de que al asignar 0 luego de leer el archivo me toca decrementar el contador:

```
Entrada[Contador - 1] = 0;
```

Comment: Por favor, consulta lo que es un [mcve], y pásate por [¿ Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Para reproducir tu problema bastan con 10 líneas de código. Un saludo.

Comment: Miraste el archivo en binario? hay un caracter de mas por lo que decis... puede ser eof.. puede ser un salto de linea... puede ser cualquier cosa....

Comment: Se supone que el contador sólo debe llegar a 11, pero llega a 12.

Comment: @Trauma. El error es el mísmo, pero la pregunta es distinta.

Comment: @CandidMoe jejeje ... pero lo que cuenta es la respuesta. Tu respuesta a aquella es perfectamente válida en esta :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que `feof(source)` marca fin de archivo después de que fracasa la lectura.

> **Return value**
>
> On success, returns the obtained character. On failure, returns EOF.
>
> If the failure has been caused by end-of-file condition, additionally
> sets the eof indicator (see feof()) on stream. If the failure has been
> caused by some other error, sets the error indicator (see ferror()) on
> stream.

El caracter extraño que lees es el EOF del fin de archivo.

La forma estándar es leer primero y preguntar después:

```
    // Leer el primer caracter.
    Caracter_Actual = fgetc(source);
    // Seguir leyendo mientras haya sido leido un caracter.
    for (Contador = 0; !(feof(source)); Contador++) // Lectura de el código fuente
    {
        printf("\nÍndice: %d\nElemento: %d\nCaracter: %c\n", Contador, Contador + 1, Caracter_Actual);
        Entrada[Contador] = Caracter_Actual;
        Caracter_Actual = fgetc(source); // Obtener un caracter
    }

    // Contador queda señalando una celda vacia
    Entrada[Contador] = 0;
```